# Set today's date as environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I need to set today's date as environment variable in my docker container.

What I am trying to do is to get today's date so I can use it to call some API with Logstash's http_poller plugin.

The solution I am thinking about is to get today's date using the command `date +%Y%m%d`

How can I set the result of this command as an environment variable at run time?

Comment: Do you mean in when you build your image or when you start your container ?

Comment: I want to use this environment variable while I am running my container.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing: _setting the variable in `Dockerfile`_ implies that you want to statically set the timestamp of _at build-time_, but your [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492739/set-todays-date-as-env-variable-in-dockerfile/65497546#comment115809245_65493281) suggest that you want to have the current date _at run-time_ set in an environment variable? Maybe you expand a bit more on the context of want you actually want to achieve since this smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/591014)

Comment: @acran, you are right, I might be confusing them as I am new to the technology, but correct, what I am looking for is to set the date at run-time not build time. I will try to update the question to avoid the confusion, any any update suggestions are very welcomed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) should be what you are looking for:

```
FROM base

# to be able to use in Dockerfile
ARG now

# to store the value as environment variable in the image
ENV build_date=$now
```

Now you can build this with

```sh
# pass value explicitly
docker build --build-arg now="$(date +%Y%m%d)" .

# pass value from environment
export now="$(date +%Y%m%d)"
docker build --build-arg now .
```

This still requires to run `date` on the host since doing this inside the `Dockerfile` is not possible unfortunately:

- The only way to execute arbitrary commands in the build is within a `RUN` statement; but
- The only way to persist a variable into the environment of an image/container is with an `ENV` statement which can only use environment variables from outside the build

You could use a custom `ENTRYPOINT` tough and inject the date to the environment from a file:

```
FROM base

RUN date +%Y%m%d > /build-timestamp
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```

`entrypoint.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

export BUILD_TIMESTAMP="$(cat /build-timestamp)"
exec "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I am looking for, I want to do this inside the Dockerfile, not outside it.

Comment: Then there is unfortunately no way to do it because `ENV` can not execute arbitrary commands. I expanded my answer to explain this also.

Comment: I have two questions 1. Will BUILD_TIMESTAMP be assigned as ENV without explicitly setting it? 2. will assigning $(cat /build-timestamp) directly to ENV work? something like `ENV MY_VALUE=$(cat /build-timestamp)`. So there will not be a script.
PS: I am very new to Docker topics.

Comment: RE 1.: no, this has actually nothing to do with `ENV` or even `docker` but is just basic shell scripting; the `entrypoint.sh` just adds this environment variable to its own process environment before executing the actual command/script that was specified with `docker run` / `CMD`

Comment: RE 2.:  also no, because as said above this would require to execute `cat /build-timestamp` (or `date +%Y%m%d` in the above case) on the host in order to use its output as a value for `ENV`. Executing a command within the container at build time is only possible with `RUN`. To use a value in the `Dockerfile` from the output of a command run on the host use `ARG` and `--build-arg` as described above. But this would set the value statically at _build time_ of the image. To set it dynamically at _run-time_ of the container, use an entrypoint script as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

So according to your answer to my comment, if you want to have the variable set at runtime you need to inject it when you start your container

```
✗ docker run -e TS=$(date +%Y%m%d) python:3.7-alpine env
TS=20201230
PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.9
HOME=/root
```

Here is the link to the docker documentation : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables

But you are confusing the Dockerfile with the container. A Dockerfile is a definition for building an image. This image is static. Then you start multiples containers from this base image.

So if your start 3 containers with the same image, according to your question you expect 3 different dates in your containers. So you see why you can't set a date or a command in a Dockerfile. The previous snippet does what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) `ENV` only supports `<key>=<value>` entries, I see no way to put it there with a command. I suggest you drop the value into some file then read it when needed. Or, if you have a launch script, using `RUN` you can add `export VAR_NAME=<value>` to the launch script so that the variable is automatically added to the environment on launch.

Comment: The suggested solution with RUN seems to be the only way to go, but then I think I need to set another cron job inside the container to update the date everyday and run the launch script.

Comment: What if you write `export VAR_NAME=<value>` into some file, like `/myvar.sh`, then source it both in cron and elsewhere? @M.Alsioufi

Comment: This could also be an option, but I think it is easier to do this in the launch script itself, because anyway I need to rerun it in order for it to read the new value of the the variable.  otherwise I need to run it from `myvar.sh` which adds a needless extra layer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to first do export command and then running service startup like this

```
CMD export INSTALL_DATE=$(date +%s) && python3 /product/server.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the solution as described by acran, to use ARG to bring outside information in. There is a second solution.

You can write the date to a file, and read the content of that file before executing your command. Here is an example Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN (date +'%Y-%m-%d %R') > date.txt
CMD x=$(cat date.txt) && echo "The build time is: $x"
```